# What changes i have to make with ip adress in order to upload the android app in play store

Tags: android

I have created an android application that uses MySQL, PHP. The php files are running locally through wamp and every time I change network I change the IP url depending on the network I am in. I want to ask what changes I have to make to upload it to the play store and run from any mobile and any network.|

```
 public static String URL_LOGIN = "http://192.168.xx.x/f_login_api/login.php";
```

Comment: You will have to deploy your API on a separate server and pass its CName (address) to your app

Comment: on which server?

Comment: Whichever server you want. You basically have to host it somewhere other than your PC (or you can keep your PC running forever and keep it hosted there)